# ViewModel with a Dynamic collection property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, collections, wpf-controls, datacontext

I am working with WPF and the MVVM pattern. So my problem is if it's possible in ViewModel of a secondary window/view have a dynamic property who will have some collection.

My App have different custom classes who are collections like Categories, Suppliers and etc, and i am trying to create a ViewModel who will have a Property to have one of those collections each time the user wants to edit the items of a collection. My doubt is if this is possible to achieve with a ViewModel.

In the ViewModel i have boolean properties to show or not Labels, TextBoxes, and some Columns in a ListView. And the Collection who will be the property in the ViewModel is binded by a ListView.

I am trying to this by this way, so i can prevent from creating a window/view for each collection to be edited.

My Classes:

```
public class SupplierCollection : CollectionBase, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    (...)
}

public class StateCollection : CollectionBase, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    (...)
}

public class PlaceCollection : CollectionBase, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    (...)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show how collction classes you've mentioned are declared? Just class signature including base class, implemented interfaces, etc. Basically I'm thinking to abstractball your collection classes by a common interface so you will be able to use it in ViewModel

Comment: I have added to my question some of my classes and which interfaces they implement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your notes right you can achieve what you want by introducing following `enum`:

```cs
enum CollectionType
{
  Suppliers,
  States,
  Places
}
```

and then add into the View Model following property:

```cs
public CollectionType CollectionToUse { get; set; }
```

then use `switch` or something more decoupled like

```cs
IDictionary<CollectionType, CollectionBase> map = ....
if (map.ContainsKey(CollectionType.States))
{
    var states = map[CollectionType.States];
}
```

Comment: I mean that the Property in the ViewModel will be one of the collections depending on the collection the user wants to make changes, or in other words, each time the user wants to edit or make changes to the items of one of the collections.

Comment: I can't understand how i will get my current collections through the enum... How i equal the fields in the enum to my collections?

Comment: No, idea is to retrieve right collection depends on COllectionToUse value like `dictionary[CollectionToUse]` - references a collection

Comment: I am trying another thing, creating a general collection, because all my collection inherits from CollectionBase, so maybe i can have one only general collection and then i create one general collection for each type of items in my MainViewModel. What you think? And it's a good idea to prevent from having too many windows and try to simplify having one dynamic like i am doing?

Comment: @Miguel : if all your entities has common interface or base class surely you can leverage this and create common collection like ICollection<IEntity> but later you should be able to cast to more specific type and this is question how to do it and answer depends on design and requirements you are following